# Spring Integration - MongoDB inbound channel adapter not working

Tags: spring-integration, spring-data-mongodb

I have configured a MongoDB inbound channel adapter. However, the inbound channel adapter is not working as expected. I tried outbound channel adapter and was successful to write some content to DB. It seems the connection is successful but the data retrieval is not successful. I don't see anything is log as well. Can anyone point out what I am missing?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
        xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
        xmlns:int-mongodb="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mongodb"
        xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mongodb http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mongodb/spring-integration-mongodb.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">

        <bean id="mongoDBFactory"
            class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
            <constructor-arg name="mongo">
                <bean class="com.mongodb.Mongo">
                    <constructor-arg name="host" value="localhost" />
                    <constructor-arg name="port" value="27017" />
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
        </bean>

        <int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter
            id="mongoInboundAdapter" channel="mongoChannel" expect-single-result="true"
            query="{'_id' : '10'}" entity-class="com.test.si.prototype.model.Order"
            collection-name="orders" auto-startup="false"
            mongodb-factory="mongoDBFactory">
            <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
        </int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter>

        <int:channel id="mongoChannel" />
        <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger"
            auto-startup="true" log-full-message="true" level="INFO" channel="mongoChannel" />

        <int:service-activator input-channel="mongoChannel"
            ref="messageListenerImpl" method="processMessage" />


        <bean id="messageListenerImpl" class="com.test.si.prototype.service.MessageListenerImpl"></bean>
    </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `<int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter>` is marked with `auto-startup="false"`. So, it isn't going to poll data from DB until you `start()` `mongoInboundAdapter` manually.

From other side you should understand that `query="{'_id' : '10'}"` isn't good. Because you will retrive from the DB only the single document and only if it has an `id == 10`.

Do you really sure that you have such a document in the `orders` collection?

Comment: I tried removing `auto-startup="false"` as well. It didn't work. I am sure that document with `id==10` exists. `db.orders.find({"_id":"10"})` is returning single document while running against the DB.

Comment: `auto-startup="true"` has no effect as well.

Comment: Is your `orders` really in the `test` Database ?

Comment: yes it is. Please notice that MongoDB out-bound channel adapter is working which I tried to check if the connection was not successful. But that is not the case here. I can write to DB with out-bound channel adapter.

Comment: Well, if you have Spring Integration source code I suggest you to debug `MongoDbMessageSource.receive()` and figure out what's going on. Your issue does not make sence for me. If this adapter hasn't worked it has been an issue here for a long time already.

Comment: I may be missing some configuration or something. That is why I pasted all the xml content I have been trying.

Comment: No, everything looks good. However you can show you test class to be sure that you block `main` Thread to wait for a data during some timeout. Because `poller` is a separate Thread and it doesn't have any effect for the main Thread.